# Kepler's first law; mathematical way of thinking

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I have Kepler's first law of planetary motion:

$$\text{r}=\frac{\text{p}}{1+\epsilon\cos\left(\theta\right)}\tag1.$$

Now, for $\epsilon$ I have:

$$0<\epsilon=\sqrt{1+\frac{2\cdot\eta\cdot\text{h}^2}{\mu^2}}<1\tag,$$

because it is an ellipse.

Now, for $\mu$:

$$\mu=\text{G}\cdot\text{M}\tag3,$$

and for $\eta$:

$$\eta=-\frac{\mu}{2\text{a}}\tag4,$$

where $\text{a}=\frac{\text{r}_\text{min}+\text{r}_\text{max}}{2}$.

Questions:

1. For the Earth's orbit around the sun, which mass ($\text{M}$) should I pick, the mass of the sun or the mass of the earth?
2. What is $\text{h}$ in the equation for $\epsilon$ and how can I find the value for it?
3. What are the values of $\text{r}_\text{min}$ and $\text{r}_\text{max}$?

Answer (score 1):

1. $M$ stands for the mass of the Sun.
2. $h$ is the angular momentum. It is defined as $\vec h=\vec r\times\vec p$, where $\vec p$ is the linear momentum. For central forces (such as the gravitational) it is conserved and perpendicular to the plane of orbit. Therefore if you know the velocity $\vec v$ of the planet as well as its radius vector $\vec r$ at a some instant, you know the angular momentum everywhere in the orbit. You can also compute its magnitude from Kepler's second law if you know the area $A$ and period $T$ of the orbit. They are related as
   $$A=\frac{hT}{2m},$$
   where $m$ is the mass of the planet.
3. $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$ are minimum and maximum distance from the planet to the Sun. It can be computed to be
   $$r_{\pm}=\frac{r_0}{1\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{E}{E_0}}},$$
   where the sign plus (minus) refers to the minimum (maximum) distance. The constant $E$ is the mechanical energy of the planet. It is a free parameter, you can write the eccentricity of the orbit in terms of it,
   $$\epsilon=\sqrt{1-\frac{E}{E_0}}.$$
   The constant $E_0$ is the smallest energy a orbit can have (circular motion),
   $$E_0=\frac{-G^2M^2m^3}{2h^2}.$$
   Finally the constant $r_0$ is the radius of the circular orbit,
   $$r_0=\frac{h^2}{GMm^2}.$$

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. How can I find $\text{r}_0$, $\text{E}$ and $\text{E}_0$? And what is $\text{r}_0$

Comment: And what are $\text{A}$ and $\text{T}$ for values?

Comment: @treq Please have another look, I replied your comments in the answer.

Comment: Oke, thanks! But what do you mean by 'free parameter'? Second what is $\text{A}$? Third is $\text{T}$ the number of seconds in a year?

Comment: It means that you should specify the energy and for each of its value you obtain the orbit. The geometry of the orbit is viewed as a function of the energy. The variable $A$ is the area of the ellipse.

Comment: Oke, what is that function of energy?

Comment: @treq As I see you are having some troubles with the concepts. There are some good books attacking this subject in a friendly level. For instance, Klepner and Kolenkow - An introduction to mechanics and Knudsen and Hjorth - Elements of Newtonian Mechanics do a good job.

Comment: Very good answer. I second Kleppener and Kolenkow's, I used it this year for my mechanics class.

Comment: Strictly speaking, M is the mass of the Sun plus the mass of the Earth. In practice, this introduces an error in the fifth or sixth decimal place with regard to the orbit of the Earth about the Sun. OTOH, since the Moon's mass is about 0.0123 times that of the Earth, ignoring the mass of the Moon in computing the mean motion results in a four hour error in the computation of the period of the Moon's orbit about the Earth.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes, that's true. And $m$ is the reduced mass. I think that when talking about Kepler's law as originally stated to describe the motion of the planets around the Sun, such details may be well neglected . Of course that in the two body problem in general that is not acceptable. Thanks for pointing this out anyway!